# AngularJS ngModelController

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

What is the correct way to check ngModelController validity?

I have a valid controller object inside of a directive. If I log the object to the console from inside the directive I get:

`console.log(ctrl)`

```
$dirty: false
$invalid: true
$modelValue: ""
$name: undefined
$pristine: true
$valid: false
$viewValue: ""
...
```

then, if I ask `if( ctrl.$valid === true )` to log the object to the console again, it does with the exact same output.

```
console.log(ctrl); //ctrl.$valid is false
if(ctrl.$valid == true) {
    console.log(ctrl); //ctrl.$valid is false
}
```

additionally if I inspect the element I can see the the appropriate `ng-invalid` class is being applied.

I will *try* to make a plunkr to demonstrate but I can't imagine I would be able to duplicate this.

**Update** If I `console.log(ctrl.$valid)` is prints `true`. So now I get how it's passing the conditional but not why the object form shows `$valid` being `false`.

Also I made a plnkr that shows an example of what I am doing but it does *not* suffer from the same problem. [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/m7UTWvj5CXFVZmk4TBzW?p=preview)

Comment: If the AngularJS digest cycle is not complete when you are looking at the `$valid` value and you have behavior that will depend on it, you may want to add either put that logic in a callback for the `ngModelController`'s array of `$viewChangeListeners` or use a `scope.$watch(...)` to try and observe changes.

Comment: Take a look at this plunker:  http://plnkr.co/edit/46zIjWBMmmoiZIEytY7w

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(ctrl));
if(ctrl.$valid == true) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(ctrl));
}
```

or

```
console.log("$valid is ", ctrl.$valid);
if(ctrl.$valid == true) {
    console.log("$valid should be true and is actually ", ctrl.$valid);
}
```

It could be related to [this](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=50316) (old) Chrome bug.  I believe the expected behavior is that when you expand the object in the console you get the value of the object at expansion time, not at log time, so you would need to print the object as a string or clone it when logging.

**Edit** - Some more details...

If you run this `var obj = {a: 1, b: {}}; console.log(obj); obj['a'] = 2; console.log(obj);` in the Chrome console you will see this being output:

```
> Object {a: 1, b: Object}
  a: 2
  b: Object
  __proto__: Object

> Object {a: 2, b: Object}
  a: 2
  b: Object
  __proto__: Object
```

**Edit 2**

Hopefully this will answer your question.  It appears that you may be adding a parser to the `$parsers` array *after* `$setViewValue(...)` has been called.  As a result, when your directive is first initialized any validations you have added will not have been executed.  You can manually execute them by calling something like `ctrl.$setViewValue(ctrl.$viewValue);` after your parser has been added.

Comment: To follow on from this answer, then, I believe the reason it appears as false in the object form when you expand it in the console is because some other code is running after the `console.log()` call that sets it back to being valid.