# Can't access last element in array but can access full array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-scope, console.log

In angularjs

I have a html table element where users can click an "add row" button once the user saves info for that row and hits save this function "checkValue()" gets called via ng-click. Here is what the function does

```
$scope.checkValue = function(index){
console.log("inside function");
console.log($scope.variables);  
console.log(index);
console.log($scope.variables[index]);
console.log($scope.variables[index].name);
console.log($scope.variables);
}
```

The problem is when I console log $scope.variables(type:array of objects) I see everything including the last element so I know the data is there, but when I try to access just the last element I get an object but without the "name" (or any other) member variable, it just returns an object with "key" member which is auto generated by the system.

Trying console.log($scope.variables[index].name); (type:string) is just undefined

At first I thought it could an issue with a race condition of sorts, but the full array is populated which is what boggles me.

The index is correct ive tried index -1 and it returns the second to last element but i need the last element

Here is the console:

[image]

Comment: With what  value `index` starts?

Comment: The index is correct ive tried index -1 and it returns the second to last element but i need the last element

Comment: Arrays start at index zero so length -1 should be the last index??

Comment: Can you show how & where you are adding

Comment: index is being passed into the function which is already massaged to be the correct index (index-1), if i apply index-1 here again its actually doing index-2

Comment: You have to be very careful when using console.log with angular (or in javascript in general). Logging an object will *not* display the object contents at the instant you executed `console.log` while logging a value *will*. It has something to do with objects being passed by reference in javascript while values are passed by value.

Comment: I bet if you log `JSON.stringify($scope.variables)` you will see something interesting. Also check out a similar question I had [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21445555/angularjs-ngmodelcontroller)

Comment: Just tried, it JSON.stringify($scope.variables) prints what I expected, the array in json format.

JSON.stringify($scope.variables[index]) prints the empty string
JSON.stringify($scope.variables[index-1]) prints just the "{" hmm interesting... looks like what ogc-nick is happening here..